# No paragraph indent (\noindent) after a block quote created with displayquote?

Tags: quoting, csquotes

Is there a way to never intend a paragraph after a long intended blockquote created with `displayquote`?

IMHO it looks ugly and serves no purpose as the vertical spacing after such a blockquote/displayquote already denotes a new paragraph.
And it is obvious a new paragraph comes after a quote.
After all, after a headline there is also no  `\parindent`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{csquotes}
\date{August 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}


\blindtext
For example Someone said:
\begin{displayquote}
    bla bla
\end{displayquote}

% here I want no intend
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image: example]

I know I can place `\noindent` there – or remove the empty lines, but this is a manual and annoying task for each quotation. Even though [people recommend it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/602622/5008962).

Comment: The empty line is an explicit instruction to start a new paragraph, it not only introduces an indent it (in general) changes the vertical spacing. Removing the blank line is not a manual task! You _manually_ added it. (You should never need `\noindent` )

Answer (score 2):

You are *forcing* a new paragraph, it is not the `displayquote` that is making an indent.

If you do not start a new paragraph then there is no indent.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{csquotes}
\date{August 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}


\blindtext
For example Someone said:
\begin{displayquote}
    bla bla
\end{displayquote}
% here I want no indent
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well… I do… yeah, hmm. Yeah makes sense. 
But semantically it *is* a new paragraph (after such a long block quote, you never continue your old paragraph). As such, IMHO, the empty line makes sense.

Comment: @rugk it is quite normal to have long quotations, or lists or displayed equations that are semantically part of a paragraph.

Comment: In this example since you didn't end the sentence before the quotation the following text is arguably part of the same sentence not only the same paragraph and should start with a lowercase letter as well as no indent. This is often seen after displayed equations. @rugk